# What is Swift String to NSString bridging overhead?

Tags: string, swift, performance, bridge

I've started to learn Swift. And I read, that Swift String is bridged to NSString when using Cocoa classes. What is an overhead of this operation?

Answer (score 6):

From the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

> Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString class.

From the Swift source -> [stdlib/public/core/String.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift)

> `String` is bridged to Objective-C as `NSString`, and a `String`
>   that originated in Objective-C may store its characters in an
>   `NSString`.  Since any arbitrary subclass of `NSString` can
>   become a `String`, there are no guarantees about representation or 
>   efficiency in this case.  Since `NSString` is immutable, it is
>   just as though the storage was shared by some copy: the first is
>   any sequence of mutating operations causes elements to be copied
>   into unique, contiguous storage which may cost `O(N)` time and
>   space, where `N` is the length of the string representation (or
>   more, if the underlying `NSString` has unusual performance
>   characteristics).

These are my conclusions from that paragraph. Note: `NSString` is immutable, I'm not sure how NSMutableString works which may be relevant depending on your specific case.

1. Bridging an `NSString` to `String` is essentially a free operation; no conversion is necessary. O(1)

   - `NSString` uses UTF-16 as it's backing store. `String` uses UTF-16 or ASCII so the two instances can use the same memory.
2. However, if you then mutate that `String` struct, all of the memory will need to be copied from the original `NSString`. O(N)

   - `String` can't modify its backing memory without also modifying the `NSString`'s memory. This is why the memory must be copied so `String` has it's own memory.

Source code for the backing [StringCore](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCore.swift) that swift uses.

Comment: While the data of the string isn't copied, is the structure copied? String objects are usually implemented in two parts, one is a dynamically-allocated array, and the other is a structure / class that points to the array and encapsulates it. I understand that the former isn't copied. Is the latter?

Comment: The String struct itself is copied yes. It's currently 3 words in size so isn't an expensive copy: 1 word for the start, 1 word for the length, and 1 word for the buffer owner. I think (but have verified) that the only overhead above a memcpy instruction would be any reference counting that deal with the buffer owner.

Comment: A memcpy for 16 bytes (vs. the 12 that we have here although they're probably the same speed) takes 0.7 nanoseconds and an Objectvie-C retain/release would take 23.3 nanoseconds. Your mileage may vary but tldr is "inconceivably fast". Source: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2016-04-15-performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-2016-edition.html